# Notice: Undefined offset: inside mysql_query array

Tags: php, mysql, post

**ERROR**
    Notice: Undefined offset

This is my PHP Code. Badly need your help Thanks!

```
    <?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $myquestion=isset($_POST["myquestion"]) ? $_POST["myquestion"] :'';//array list of questions
    $myrating=isset($_POST["myrating"]) ? $_POST["myrating"] : '';


    $maxrating=count($myrating);
    $sa="succesfully added";

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['copyquestion']=$myquestion;
    mysql_select_db('new_db',$con);


     if (is_array($myquestion)&&is_array($myrating))

    for($x=0;$x<count($myquestion);$x++){
//Error Code                                                                              
         if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO question_table(question,rating,desc1,desc2,desc3,desc4,desc5,desc6,desc7,desc8,desc9,desc10)
    VALUES
      ('$myquestion[$x]','$maxrating','$myrating[0]','$myrating[1]','$myrating[2]','$myrating[3]','$myrating[4]','$myrating[5]','$myrating[6]','$myrating[7]','$myrating[8]','$myrating[9]')"));

    }

    echo $sa;

    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: just concat the usual way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Undefined offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194234/php-undefined-offset)

Comment: You've to migrate to PDO or mysqli anyway.